# How to write stack exception in JLabel of Swing?

Tags: java, swing, exception, jlabel

I have to write stack exceptions in a label and a log file:

```
try {
   ...
} catch(Exception e) {
    File file = new File(pathFile + "//error.log");
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(file);
    e.printStackTrace(ps);
    ps.close();
}
```

How to write `e` in a Swing `JLabel` too?

Comment: 1) Use a logging API. 2) Call `theLabel.setText(e.getMessage());` but note that the message will be a single line (the label can handle) rather than the detailed trace in the stack trace. For that, you'd need a multi-line component like a `JTextArea`. 3) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [mre].

Comment: if you want to see a full stack trace, this [Error Display Dialog](https://github.com/ggleblanc2/error-display-dialog#readme) might help.

Comment: To should really be doing this in a try block in the except block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a [JOptionPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

```java
catch (Exception e) {
    java.io.StringWriter sw = new java.io.StringWriter();
    java.io.PrintWriter pw = new java.io.PrintWriter(sw);
    e.printStackTrace(pw);
    String stackTrace = sw.toString();
    javax.swing.JTextArea textArea = new javax.swing.JTextArea(stackTrace);
    javax.swing.JScrollPane scrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane(textArea);
    javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                              scrollPane,
                                              e.toString(),
                                              javax.swing.JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

Note that the first argument in the call to method `showMessageDialog` is null since the code in your question does not show any *Swing* components. You should try to use an actual component from your GUI rather than null.

The second argument to method `showMessageDialog` is an [Object](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html) which basically means it can be anything you like. In the above code it is a [scroll pane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html). `JOptionPane` knows how to handle and display it.

Method `printStackTrace`, in class `java.lang.Throwable` is overloaded. The above code demonstrates one way to get the entire stack trace as a single string. Refer to the *javadoc* for method [printStackTrace](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace(java.io.PrintWriter)) and `PrintWriter` [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintWriter.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.io.Writer)) and class [StringWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/StringWriter.html).

In fact, I have a utility class.

```java
public class MessageWindow {
    public static void showError(Exception e) {
        java.io.StringWriter sw = new java.io.StringWriter();
        java.io.PrintWriter pw = new java.io.PrintWriter(sw);
        e.printStackTrace(pw);
        String stackTrace = sw.toString();
        javax.swing.JTextArea textArea = new javax.swing.JTextArea(stackTrace);
        javax.swing.JScrollPane scrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane(textArea);
        javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                                  scrollPane,
                                                  e.toString(),
                                                  javax.swing.JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Then I just call the method from the `catch` block.

```java
catch (Exception e) {
    MessageWindow.showError(e);
}
```